# Is there a hook that allows us to store variable thats dependent on which page is the user in

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Currently I'm trying to find a way to store value (given that value is a shared variable) depending which page the user is in right now. For example
User is in page A , Value is 1
User is in page B , Value is 2

Comment: I think `react-router` can be used here. Each router can have its own state: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/history. Search for `state` here please. You'll get to know about it and how you can use it.

Comment: The concept is available in v6 too.